# Does Microsoft Security Essentials replace Windows Defender?

Tags: security, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials, anti-spyware

Does Microsoft Security Essentials replace Windows Defender?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes. Windows Defender protects against adware and spyware, while MSE does all that and more (protection from viruses, rootkits, etc).

MSE will actually **disable Windows Defender** to manage your PC's realtime protection. Also, from the Security Essentials Wikipedia page:

> Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE)
>   (Previously codenamed Morro) is a free
>   antivirus software created by
>   Microsoft that provides protection
>   against viruses, spyware, rootkits,
>   and trojans for Windows XP, Vista, and
>   7.
>
> **MSE replaces Windows Live OneCare — a
>   subscription antivirus service — and
>   Windows Defender, which only protects
>   users from adware and spyware.**

Comment: What he says it true, Michael. He is telling the truth!

Comment: It should be noted that in windows 8 and 8.1, Windows Defender has vastly improved towards the older windows versions and is basically a full malware protection. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_start/windows-defender-and-microsoft-security-essentials/5309cb8d-02e1-40e8-974f-0dcedb9ab9fd for more info.

Comment: Windows Defender says it protects against viruses now.

Answer (score 3):

There's been an update. Windows Defender now replaces Microsoft Security Essentials in Windows 8 and 8.1

source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download

Comment: You seem to be missing my point.  Don't worry about me.  I will just reverse my vote.